# StringTokenizer getting whole line

Tags: java, io, stringtokenizer

I'm using StringTokenizer to read my game map. Problem is that I don't know how to get a **whole** line of the file. For example  here's my .txt file

```
Block 128 0 52 3
Block 192 0
SpeedItem 200 64
Block 256 0
Platform 150 70 500 0 false
Block 320 0 12 75
Block 384 0
```

And here how I try to print **whole** line

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("data/" + level + ".txt");
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(file.readString());
        while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            String type = tokens.nextToken();
            System.out.println(type); // with this I only get the first word of the line
            if(type.equals("Block")){
                list.add(new Brick(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
            }
```

So here's my results

```
Block
Block
SpeedItem
Block
Platform
Block
Block
```

But I also need to print all numbers in that lines for example

```
 Block 128 0 52 3
    Block 192 0
    SpeedItem 200 64
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: The javadoc says _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code._ It seems it would be easier to read lines using a BufferedReader and then split each line at whitespace. That way you can get the number of tokens in the line easily.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using StringTokenizer class? It's legacy class. Use [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method. It will make job much simpler for you.

Comment: But as You can see my txt file have Strings, Integers, Booleans and so on... Add in first line there are 4 numbers, in second lineonly two and so on... so how I need to cast everything?